# Add percentage to value based on value on previous row in pandas Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to add a percentage to a value like shown in this image [image: spreadsheet showing sample data]. The percentage in this case for 2004 is 0.5 and will be added to the previous year (2003) base value=34. I want to do this for every group of regions, products, and sub-products.

| Regions | Products | Subproducts | Years | Pct | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | X | x1 | 2003 | 0.1 | 34 |
| A | X | x1 | 2004 | 0.5 | 51 (34*(1+0.5) |
| B | X | x1 | 2003 | 0.66 | 20 |
| B | X | x1 | 2004 | 0.4 | 28 (20*(1+0.4) |

I've seen a couple answers but none of them seems to fit.

I'd really appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance

I'm trying to use the chain method to use the functions in one line, avoiding loops. But can try any approach.

Comment: You forgot to include your current code.

Comment: I don't have a code yet, I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: Also clarify if `34` is the base value for all groups or if you have it in the original DataFrame (provide a reproducible example with at least 2 groups)

Comment: 34 is the base value for that group, but it changes for every group. it is the first value on year 2003 for each of them

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [`cumprod`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumprod.html):

```
start = 34

df['Value'] = (df['Pct'].add(1).cumprod()
               .mul(start/(df['Pct'].iloc[0]+1))
              )
```

Output:

```
   Year   Pct   Value
0  2003  0.10  34.000
1  2004  0.50  51.000
2  2005  0.30  66.300
3  2006  0.00  66.300
4  2007  0.07  70.941
```

If you have several groups, then make a custom function and use it per group:

```
def f(s, start):
    return (s.add(1).cumprod()
             .mul(start/(s.iloc[0]+1))
            )

starts = {('A', 'X', 'x1'): 34,
          ('B', 'X', 'x1'): 34,
         }

df['Value'] = (df.groupby(['Regions', 'Products', 'Subproducts'],
                          group_keys=False)
                 ['Pct'].apply(lambda g: f(g, starts[g.name]))
               )
```

If the Value column already exists with the starting points:

```
g = (df.assign(x=lambda d: d['Pct'].add(1))
       .groupby(['Regions', 'Products', 'Subproducts'])
    )
df['Value'] = (g['x'].cumprod()
               .mul(g['Value'].transform('first')
                    .div(g['Pct'].transform('first').add(1))
                   )
              )
```

Output:

```
  Regions Products Subproducts  Years   Pct  value  Value
0       A        X          x1   2003  0.10     34   34.0
1       A        X          x1   2004  0.50     51   51.0
2       B        X          x1   2003  0.66     20   34.0
3       B        X          x1   2004  0.40     28   47.6
```

Comment: How can I make the start change for every group?